# How to change css property name using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following div with "left: Random Number" inline style so I tried to use most of css change functions but no luck .. the problem that I property of left is random and I want to change left to right.

```
<div class="portfolio" style="left:0">Content</div>
<div class="portfolio" style="left:230">Content</div>
<div class="portfolio" style="left:446">Content</div>
<div class="portfolio" style="left:841">Content</div>
```

I want jQuery to change all left to right not the property

I tried this but didn't work

```
$(".portfolio").css({"left": "", "right": ""});
```

also tried this

```
$(".portfolio").css({"left", "right"});
```

so any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to change `left:0` to `right:0` and `left:230` to `right:230` (side note: they'll need units, like `px`), then you need to read the original value, then write the new value and clear the original. This will need to be on an individual-element basis since the `left`s are different:

```
$(".portfolio").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var left = $this.css("left");
    $this.css({left: "", right: left});
});
```

Live Example (I've added units to the `left` values [`px`]):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".portfolio").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var left = $this.css("left");
        $this.css({left: "", right: left});
    });
    $("#header").text("After:");
}, 500);
```

```css
.portfolio {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Before:</div>
<div class="portfolio" style="left:0px">Content</div>
<div class="portfolio" style="left:230px">Content</div>
<div class="portfolio" style="left:446px">Content</div>
<div class="portfolio" style="left:841px">Content</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```